# Rails form with active record association - drag and drop upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, drag-and-drop, paperclip

I have a 'Comment' table which has many comment attachments. When comments are created, if any file is added to the comments then comment attachments are to be created.

I want the file upload to happen by ajax. But the request goes to the controller. How to save attachments only after the form submits?

I am using paperclip and jquery filer.

Answer (score 0):

If Paperclip is not a mandate, I would suggest you use [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for this. It uses an ajax call and fairly easy to integrate.